# C# Live wallpaper

Tags: c#, windows, file, live-wallpaper

i'm trying to make a live wallpaper, i use the SystemParametersInfo method but it's very slow, 1 frame takes about 3 seconds to install, i have a folder with 250 frames and i put them on the desktop one by one in a loop, tell me how to do it right?

Code here:

```
private async void LoopFrame(string folder, int framesCount)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (i > framesCount) i = 0;

                string framePath = $"{folder}\\_Frame{i}.jpg";
                SystemParametersInfo(0x14, 0, framePath, 0x01 | 0x02)
                i++;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: How fast are you expecting this to run? `SystemParametersInfo` probably wasn't designed to update the desktop wallpaper regularly enough to constitute a 'live' wallpaper. There's nothing else in that code that should take any significant amount of time to run. You've also got no control over frame rate here, assuming `SystemParametersInfo` did return almost instantly you'd use 100% of a CPU core just to run the live wallpaper and it'd update at potentially thousands of frames per second.

Comment: VLC allows you to set video wallpapers, perhaps this link has some useful information for you? https://superuser.com/q/678670/1208562 Hint for starting a process in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-6.0